# Fedora 38: Can't use ethernet

Tags: fedora, network-interface, ethernet

I'm currently trying to switch to Fedora but cant get the communication through wired connection to work.

I can't figure out what's wrong, from the computers side everything is fine, but I can't access the internet.

Right now I'm using this pc with a wifi-extension card but I'd prefer to use my lan, as I did with windows on here.

From `lspci -v -s` I get:

```
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I217-LM (rev 04)
    DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 18e7
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 28
    Memory at f7f00000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
    Memory at f7f3d000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
    I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e
    Kernel modules: e1000e
```

.. so theres a driver and i checked, its the right one.

From `ifconfig` I get:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::d7ca:22ac:2be6:6e32  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 fd00::f44d:810d:f682:c4  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 64:51:06:52:33:54  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8550  bytes 1058180 (1.0 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 5512  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 336  bytes 45969 (44.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 20  memory 0xf7f00000-f7f20000
```

.. but theres no ipv4 address, so is it my routers fault?

I've tried the following:

First I reinstalled the driver, made it even worse (It didn't connect after, just got an error something like "Cant activate ethernet connection").

I've read a few posts related to this problem and added `pcie_aspm=off` to my kernel line.

I really don't know any further so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try `sudo ethtool eno1` to see if the link and the speed/duplex settings of the other end have been detected correctly. Also `sudo ethtool -S eno1` should show a longer list of packet/error counters, which might help in identifying why the wired connection is dropping incoming packets.

Sometimes the Energy-Efficient Ethernet feature of modern NICs can confuse older network switches/routers. You can see the status of this feature with:

```
sudo ethtool --show-eee eno1
```

The response might look like this:

```
EEE settings for eno1:
        EEE status: enabled - active
        Tx LPI: 17 (us)
        Supported EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                   1000baseT/Full
        Advertised EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                    1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised EEE link modes:  100baseT/Full
                                                 1000baseT/Full
```

If the "Link partner advertised EEE link modes" is empty, then the switch/router at the other end of the cable is not claiming to support EEE, and might be confused by it. In that case, see if it helps to tell your NIC to stop trying to use EEE:

```
sudo ethtool --set-eee eno1 eee off
```

If this helps, you might want to persistently disable the EEE feature, so it won't re-activate after a reboot. There's many ways to do this; here is one that should be pretty much independent of how your network configuration is managed.

To persistently disable EEE, create a systemd unit template file named `/etc/systemd/system/disable-eee@.service` with the following contents:

```
[Unit]
Description=Disable EEE for %i
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-%i.device
DefaultDependencies=no

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/ethtool --set-eee %i eee off
ExecStop=/usr/sbin/ethtool --set-eee %i eee on
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install] 
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then run:

```
sudo systemctl enable disable-eee@eno1.service
```

to make it persistent, and

```
sudo systemctl start disable-eee@eno1.service
```

to activate it immediately without a reboot.

If you need to apply this to other network interfaces, you'll just need the last two commands, altering the name of the network interface as needed.

---

These lines in `ifconfig eno1` output indicate that more than half of all received packets have been dropped by the NIC:

```
    RX packets 8550  bytes 1058180 (1.0 MiB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 5512  overruns 0  frame 0
```

Googling for "Intel I217-LM dropped packets" tells me that Dell OptiPlex 9020 SFF and HP EliteDesk 800 G1 systems have had similar symptoms and the cause was apparently the physical connector component used: [a UDE RU1H251NRW2F](https://web.archive.org/web/20190105211055/http://www.ude-corp.com/frontproduct/product3/lang/en/SmallId/37.html) RJ45 jack + 2x USB 2.0 Port. [See this thread on Intel's own support forum.](https://community.intel.com/t5/Ethernet-Products/I217-LM-huge-packetloss-with-WaitAutoNegComplete-On-and/td-p/544926/page/2)

The `Subsystem:` line in your `lspci -v -s` output indicates your system is some Hewlett-Packard model. You should check HP support pages for your system model: if this issue can impact your model, I expect HP might have issued a support notice about it.

Since Intel is [apparently planning to "begin the product discontinuance process" on I217-LM](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/60019/intel-ethernet-connection-i217lm.html) during the last quarter of this year, I assume that your system is not so new that warranty replacement would be an option if it is suffering from this issue.

Comment: Sadly the EEE incompatibility wasnt it. 

When running `sudo ethtool --show-eee eno1` the response looks exactly like yours. 

When running `sudo ethtool -S eno1` the output seems to be fine, without any errors. 

When running any other command, I also didnt find anything wrong.

Comment: This got me a bit further, I think. Thank you!

I did do a bit of research on compatibility, but as I found out now, not enough:
I already looked my motherboard up on [this side](https://linux-hardware.org/?id=pci:8086-153a-103c-18e7), but I overlooked that, indeed, the I217-LM needed some additional driver called "netmap".

Now, Im trying to install said driver but, as Im rather new to linux or rather redhat distros, Im having some problems; when running `make`, the command returns errors from the makefile. Are there some c compilers I have to install or something like that?

Comment: From the netmap github page: "Netmap is mostly useful for userspace applications that must deal with raw packets: traffic generators, sinks, monitors, loggers, software switches and routers, generic middleboxes, interconnection of virtual machines." It is not a regular network driver nor a requirement for I217-LM: it is an optional extra if you use your system as a high-traffic QEMU/KVM virtualization host or do something else that requires dealing with raw packets in userspace. And yes, if you plan to build something from source, you are going to need a compiler and other development tools.